# $Q=(P+\frac12I)$ is invertible where $P$ is a square matrix with integral entries

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $P $ be $n×n$ matrix with integral entries and $Q=P+\frac12I$  where I denote the $n×n$ identity matrix . Then  $Q$ is invertible.

My attempt to prove:

$Q$ is invertible iff $0$ is not an eigen value.

If possible, let $0$ be eigen value. Then $\exists$ $v\in R^n$ s.t $Qv=0$

Then $Pv=-\frac12v$. So $-\frac12$ is an eigen value of $P$ with eigen vector $v$ .

So $(2x+1)$ is a divisor of the characteristics polynomail $p(x)$ (say) of $P$ which is of course a monic polynomial with integer coefficients.

So $\exists g(x)$ s.t $(2x+1)g(x)=p(x)$ .

I am not sure how to proceed from here because $g(x)$ may not itself be monic but the product is monic. . This may be  elementary question but please guide me if I am wrong or give a better proof.A lot of thanks for your time!!

Comment: I don't understand : "Q is invertible iff 0 is not (one of its) eigenvalue(s)." is true for any $Q$...

Answer (score 4):

It suffices to prove that $2Q$ is invertible. But $2Q$ is an integer matrix with all even entries except for odd entries on the diagonal. In other words, $2Q\equiv I\pmod2$, and so $\det(2Q)\equiv \det(I)=1\pmod2$. In particular, $\det(2Q)$ is an odd integer and hence nonzero, so $2Q$ is invertible. (And $\det Q$ is an odd integer divided by $2^n$, which could probably be proved directly if desired.)

Comment: @GregMartin..Thanks for your answer sir. But I am a little confused. What does taking determinant over congruent matrices mean?

Comment: $2Q$ and $I$ are matrices with integer entries, and so their (regular) determinants are integers. Any two integers might or might not be congruent (mod $2$). It turns out to be true (and is a good exercise to check) that if matrices $M=(m_{ij)}$ and $N=(n_{ij})$ are integer matrices such that $m_{ij}\equiv n_{ij}\pmod q$ for all $i$ and $j$, then $\det M \equiv \det N\pmod q$ as well.

Comment: Oh ..I see , thanks for the informative reply.

Answer (score 1):

$Q$ is invertible iff $2Q$ is invertible. In $2Q$, the diagonal entries are all *odd* and the off-diagonal entries are all *even*. Now if we apply the Leibniz formula for $\det2Q$
$$\det 2Q=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)\prod_{i=1}^n(2Q)_{i,\sigma(i)}$$
we see that the identity permutation corresponds to a selection of exactly the diagonal entries, which multiply to an odd number, while all other permutations correspond to a selection containing at least one even entry, so their contribution to the sum is even. $\det2Q$ is thus the sum of one odd and several even numbers, which must be odd, hence necessarily non-zero. So $2Q$ is invertible, implying $Q$ is invertible as well.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, the characteristic polynomial of $P$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients. The leading and last coefficients are
$$ x^n + \dots + (-1)^n \det P$$
By the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), all rational eigenvalues of $P$ must be integer divisors of $\det P$. In particular,  $-1/2$ cannot be an eigenvalue.

Comment: (Found the question in the [Math Chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61317222#61317222). This seems easier than the other answers.)